# MySQL 5.7 (PHP) Compare two json arrays and get dfference

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have table `films` with columns `id` | `array_of_img`

Column `array_of_img` contains JSON array like ["1","2","3"]

I also have a session variable array `$session_var` = [1,2], which after `json_encode` becomes ["1","2"].

So my goal is to get single random integer value, which is not in `$session_var` but in one of the `films` rows in column `array_of_img`.

In the example above the result must be `3`.

Possible logics:

- merge two json's and delete duplicates
- somehow get UNIQUE elements comparing two json's

I've looked through these functions, but didn't understand how to use them with my situation:

- JSON_CONTAINS
- JSON_OVERLAPS (ver. of MySQL> 5.7)
- JSON_KEYS
- JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE
- JSON_MERGE_PATCH

Some code to see syntax

```
$session_var = json_encode($session_var);
$query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Without MySQL 8+, this would probably be easier to do in PHP.

Comment: @Nick Thank you very much. I guess I've done what you mean.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. If you do upgrade to MySQL 8, you could use `JSON_TABLE` on the two JSON values and use an anti-join to get the values which are not in both.

Answer (score -1):

Thank's to [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick) advice I made some workarround and did this.

```
require_once 'connection.php';
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Error_connect_1 " . mysqli_error($link));

session_start();
$session_var = $_SESSION["arr_of_img"] ? $_SESSION["arr_of_img"] : [];

//count possible variants [summary of json_length_field]
$query = "SELECT SUM(JSON_LENGTH(arr_of_img)) AS summary FROM films WHERE show_this IS NULL";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error_connect_2 " . mysqli_error($link));
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$summary = $result['summary'];

//get the whole table and random it
$query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE show_this IS NULL ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error_connect_2 " . mysqli_error($link));
$table = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//walk through the table and find array of different values
foreach ($table as $row) {
    $arr_of_img_db = $row['arr_of_img'];
    $arr_of_img_db = json_decode($arr_of_img_db);
    $result = array_diff($arr_of_img_db, $session_var);
    if ($result) break;
}

//get single random value and get image by this value
if ($result) {
    $arr_of_img = $result;
    $img = array_rand($arr_of_img, 1);
    $img = $arr_of_img[$img];

    $query2 = "SELECT id, src as img,show_this  FROM img WHERE id LIKE '" . $img . "' AND show_this IS NULL LIMIT 1";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die("Error_connect_2 " . mysqli_error($link));
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

echo json_encode($result);
mysqli_close($link);
```